# Implicit vals in traits behave differently with type annotation

Tags: scala

Just wondering if the following is a bug or a feature:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-M3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class TypeClass[T]
defined class TypeClass

scala> trait A[T] {
     |   implicit val t = implicitly[TypeClass[T]]
     | }
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: TypeClass[T]
         implicit val t = implicitly[TypeClass[T]]
                                    ^
```

As expected, this doesn't compile because there's no constraint on `T`. But when I add a type annotation it compiles:

```
scala> trait A[T] {
     |   implicit val t: TypeClass[T] = implicitly[TypeClass[T]]
     | }
defined trait A
```

Shouldn't the compiler be complaining here? Why should a type annotation make a difference? If we instantiate something with this trait, `t` is `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you are just scr**ing yourself here. :-)

You just declared that the implicit `TypeClass[T]` is `val t`. That is, `val t = t`, which makes it null. Ouch!

`T` is abstract, so the compiler cannot provide a `TypeClass` for it. You'd have to get that with the `T` parameter, but you won't be able to in a `trait`. In a `class`, make it `T : TypeClass`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's neither bug nor feature, just a consequence of some features.

In the first example, there is no implicit value of type `TypeClass[T]` in scope. You rely on type inference to know the type of `t` and since implicits are resolved at compile time, the type of `t` is not defined because the implicit value can't be found.

In the second example there is a suitable implicit value in scope, namely `t`. If you did not allow that behavior in general you couldn't do recursive definitions like:

```
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map{case (x,y) => x+y}
```